# Блоки - как вытянуть данные

Tags: ios, post, request, objective-c

Доброе время суток, в общем изучаю POST запрос и библиотеку AFNetworking, я отправляю POST запрос:

```
parameters = @{@"login": @"123",@"password" : @"123"};
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:@"http://---" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

     NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {          NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

Как вытянуть данные из responseObject в глобальную переменную? И как можно отправлять информацию без блоков? уж больно они бесят

Comment: можете использовать старый добрый delegate, хотя он настолько сильно уступает блокам, что в AFNetworking его скорее всего уже нет. Только есть в предыдущих версиях. А что не так с блоками? Оч. удобный и сильный инструмент! Возьмите как вариант глобальную переменную и присвойте ее внутри блока, если она у вас static id receivedData; все должно быть ок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых блоки наше все, без блоков вообще жизнь не жизнь. Блоки- это ангел спаситель в obj-c мире. На них написан MVVM (ReactiveCocoa), и много что еще. Не избегайте блоков, изучите их.
Что касается вопроса. В чем проблема в получении данных? Поставьте брекпоинт на строчку `NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);` что за данные там лежат? Если это словарь, то выдергивайте из него как из словаря. Если бинарные данные, то как NSData. Ну и так далее.

Comment: @Bimawa ну например есть переменная id newData, и в нутки блока я пишу newData = responseObject;
компилятор выдает ошибку, типа нельзя присваивать внутри блока данные в глобальную переменную

Comment: можно, прекрасно рабоатет для меня. static id newData; - объявляем, внутри блока присваиваем

Comment: @VladimirBabochin изучите, как работают блоки. Они не имеют права просто так брать и присваивать переменные, так как они работают с копией данных. Если Вы ходитте присвоить переменную, то ее нужно изначально подготовить для этого и поставить модификатор __block. Просто прочитайте любую статью http://habrahabr.ru/post/119877/ и на айдеве очень хороший пример: http://idev.by/ios/21061/

Comment: Спасибо Вам :)